# Error found when loading etc/profile:

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I tried to upgrade CUDA version to 11 and run into some errors and tried fixing the NVIDIA drivers
Now when I boot my system it shows the following statements

**Error found when loading etc/profile:
jetc/profile.d/cuda.sh: line 2: export: CUDADIRustical data
identifier
As a result the session will not be configured correctly You should fix the problem as soon as feasible**
How can I fix this error?

Comment: You can start by adding in your Q /etc/profile, and all bashrc files that it `sources`/`includes`, and also adding the contents of `jetc/profile.d/cuda.sh`

Comment: Please show content of the `/etc/profile`.

Comment: i find these in the end of .bashrc file "# set PATH for cuda 10.2 installation
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:$PATH"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Comment: Also the below lines under /etc/profile.d/cuda.sh                                                    "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export CUDADIR-usr/local/cuda"